# How to show a dialog message when internet connection is not available using html jquery or java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, connection

I want to show a dialog message ["internet connection is not avialable"] if i click a login button when internet connection is not available using jquery or java script

Comment: You can set a timer to periodically run an AJAX get request for a dummy page. Store whether it succeeded or failed in a bool, then check that bool when the user clicks the login button

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384167/check-if-internet-connection-exists-with-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/javascript-how-to-detect-that-the-internet-connection-is-offline

Answer (score 0):

[navigator.onLine returns a boolean in most browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Online_and_offline_events)

Comment: i am working in mobile apps.sonavigator.onLine is not working in mobile webkit browser..