# How to detect internet connection type using java script?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, servlets, connection

In web based application, I am using JSP and servlets. When user will access the application from his computer than user should aware that what connection he/she is using. How can i detect the user's internet connection type and show it on the page ?

Actually, I want to detect connection type i.e. whether user is using proxy or direct(using USB modem) internet.

Is there any possibility to check this using java-script ? If not then what are the possible ways to do this?

Comment: check this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384167/check-if-internet-connection-exists-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested to know if there is a one but im sure javascript does not have enough previlleges to detect that

Comment: is it possible to detect the same in server-side using java and get it display in user's page ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

var online = navigator.onLine;

checkout the below lines :

```
var connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;

function updateConnectionStatus() {
  alert("Connection bandwidth: " + connection.bandwidth + " MB/s");
  if (connection.metered) {
    alert("The connection is metered!");
  }
}

connection.addEventListener("change", updateConnectionStatus);
updateConnectionStatus();
```

Comment: will it work in case of web application in browser like ie, chrome or mozila ?

Comment: it's working perfectly in mozilla in my code .you can check in onload function..by this line .. alert(""+navigator.onLine);

Comment: @suresh Thanks i also tested this but still my problem is to get connection type and show it user. Could you plz tell me how to achieve that ?

Comment: check this link once https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.connection