# Determine if connection is dead on clientside

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a site which have a div in updatepanel, which is refreshed every 10 seconds, and I pass string result to div. If connection is dead, i get error that server is unavailable, which should not happen.

My question is, how to check clientside if connection is down, so I can just pass empty string to that div, and that page remains.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe there is no way to do this check using JavaScript, try working on the error handling return. However, show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

[Check if Internet Connection Exists with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384167/check-if-internet-connection-exists-with-javascript)

If you need an immediate solution, you could use this:

```
var online = navigator.onLine;
```