# Constant internet activity check

Tags: javascript, windows-8, android-activity

I'm trying to work on an automatic internet activity check. However, I didn't find a result. I'm also not sure whetever I should create a background task or not for this.

Basically what I want sounds very simple. I would like the app to notify the user immediately whenever he lost his internet connection. But how would I do this? I've been searching for over two hours now without a result. I did find functions how to look for an internet connection manually.

I hope anyone is able to help me out!

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384167/check-if-internet-connection-exists-with-javascript

Comment: @epascarello I already read that question and it unfortunately did not answer my question. I would like the user to be notified immediately, automatically, as soon as the user loses his connection.

Comment: So you poll it, Do you not know about setTimeout/setInterval?

Comment: @epascarello I do, hoever I thought the use of timers could be avoided. I' m not sure what it is like in javascript, however in Game Development I learned you should use as less timers as possible.

Comment: Well that is your only option here, there are no events that fire when the internet connection is dropped, you have to poll to check it.