# navigator.onLine is returns true when there is no internet connection

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-connection

navigator.onLine is always returns true when there is no internet connection in firefox
but ie10 and google chrome is working correctly.

I'm using firefox version 19.

How to check internet connection using javascript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only thing you can do is try it out. Ping your service and wait for a response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if Internet Connection Exists with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384167/check-if-internet-connection-exists-with-javascript)