# Checking internet connection in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen many questions about this topic in stack overflow but only one code helped me to do it and that code is in [Check if Internet Connection Exists with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384167/check-if-internet-connection-exists-with-javascript) As I don't have 50 reputations I couldn't comment under the post by morespace54

```
<script>
function doConnectFunction() {
// Grab the GOOGLE CMD
}
function doNotConnectFunction() {
// Grab the LOCAL JQ
}

var i = new Image();
i.onload = doConnectFunction;
i.onerror = doNotConnectFunction;
// CHANGE IMAGE URL TO ANY IMAGE YOU KNOW IS LIVE
i.src = 'http://gfx2.hotmail.com/mail/uxp/w4/m4/pr014/h/s7.png?d=' + escape(Date());
// escape(Date()) is necessary to override possibility of image coming from cache
</script>
```

So my doubt is "Is there any problem in using this link http://gfx2.hotmail.com/mail/uxp/w4/m4/pr014/h/s7.png Do I have to worry about copyright issues If yes then can anyone help me with a link that doesn't have any copyright issues"

Comment: You could use a link/image from your own server and never worry about copyright!

Comment: i tried using an image i.src = 'http://www.slideshare.net/dominicsavio1460/spelling-bee-21131224?related=1'; but this is not working and not giving me the expected output

Comment: use this: http://image.slidesharecdn.com/spellingbee-130513191131-phpapp02/95/spelling-bee-1-638.jpg?cb=1368490399 instead

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal issues of copyright.

Comment: wow Amy you are really awsome. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use that image for whatever, as long as you don't use it commercially.