# switching between online and offline javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm building a mobile application with html5 and javascript. I have json data in js file. I will host that data file on my online server to update the data daily but  I want my application to use the local file when there is no internet connection available too.

Thank you

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384167/check-if-internet-connection-exists-with-javascript?lq=1 Essentially, if Ajax fails, assume connection went offline, then load alternate local source.

Comment: Thank you @noahnu
Now when I use the online data file the application does not work, it works only when I use the local file.

Comment: Post that as a question w/ a snippet of your code plus any errors you get (i.e. from developer console).