# How to include jquery online version, or fall back to offline if not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, offline, fallback

On my site I have included the google version of jquery like so:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But of course this fails when I am offline. I have downloaded the file to a local location, so I can serve it up using my own web server (e.g. http://127.0.0.1/jquery.min.js) even if the internet is not available on this computer. But as a rule I'd prefer to use to online version if it is available. How can I specify the local version as a fallback, if the online version is not available?

Comment: You can attach an `onerror` event handler to it, eg. `<script src=... onerror="loadLocalJQ()">`

Comment: check answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384167/check-if-internet-connection-exists-with-javascript