# Top-of-page element superimposed on HTML

Tags: html, css

### How to add a div at the top of the overlay page?

I need to create a div that stays over all the elements of the page at the top when the internet connection is not active according to the image below, in what way using CSS I can create this div with * ngIf as an example below.

```
    <div *ngIf="connection_refused" class="connection-status-wrap">
<span class="connection-status-text">No connection to server</span>
</div>
```

I am verifying if there is internet connection, when not having internet connection should display the above div on all elements of the page at the top.

[Image Example: Div on top page elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vaHb.png)

Comment: Refer to [CSS `position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: You can do it using css. Apply a css class to the div with {position: absolute; top: 0px; left 0px;} you may have to also use z-index so it shows over other content

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384167/check-if-internet-connection-exists-with-javascript) post, please.

Comment: @AndresM 
I do not have much knowledge in front-end development, thanks for the collaboration (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
window.setInterval(function(){
if (navigator.onLine) {
    //if its offline, show div.
} else {
    //else (when the connection return) hide div.
}}, 5000); // every 5 seconds, function check if has connection
```

And use Position: fixed, top: 0, and define width and height;

Answer (score 0):

For keeping the element at the top of the page, a fixed position should work just fine

```
position:fixed;
top:0%;
```

However, if there is a stable connection and you wish to hide the element from the viewer, you could either set the [visibility](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) of the element in css

```
visibility: hidden;
```

Hope this helped!